# Unable to run android eclipse project due to unfigured errors

Tags: android, eclipse

These are the errors that i am getting when i attempt to run my project. It was working perfectly fine till yesterday. I have no idea what is causing the error. I cleaned the project and reran a number of times. I even restarted my laptop, but in vain.  Please help me restore this, its a very huge project. 
My friends copied the project on his laptop and was able to run it successfully. Which concludes that there has been a problem with my eclipse.

[image: Errors in the error log when i attempt to run the project]
[image: Errors in the error log when i attempt to run the project]

Comment: From what I can seem these are coming from Eclipse or ADT, not your project. So, in worst case scenario, if you don't find another answer and you need it fast, try re-installing Eclipse. Again, this should be your last resort.

Comment: close the unrelated project, run your application

Comment: Yes the prob is with eclipse ... coz none of the projects are running

Comment: i closed all unrelated projects.. and cleaned ... but errors still persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many errors to sort out.  I would very much recommend the easy way out which is to uninstall Eclipse (in case it really is the source of the problem) re-install it and start up a new project, then slowly add in the project files one by one.  At least this way if the error comes back you know which file it is (if any).  Best of luck.

Comment: I had to re-install eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try to update eclipse if there is any update to apply.